# After Login on Sitecore CMS does not redirect to Content Editor and throws error 500 - The request timed out

Tags: azure, paas, identity-server, cms-only

I have deployed our Application on PROD CM and CD instance on the `Azure PAAS` and the instance is working fine. When I try to log in to the CM instance, I can log in, but instead of redirecting me to the Sitecore Content Editor it's throwing me an error `500 - The request timed out. The webserver failed to respond within the specified time`.

After logging into the CM site, the following error is displayed: `500 - The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within the specified time`

After login into the CM instance:
[image]

[image]

I have verified the `AllowedCorsOrigins` and Redirect URL in the identity server and CM instance in both `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` and `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config` respective files and all are correct.

The same code and deployment work perfectly with the `Pre-PROD environment` on the `Azure PAAS`.

`Sitecore Version 10.2`

Comment: Did you check Chrome Dev Tools console for any errors/issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing data from a period of time where there was an issue with slow `/identity/externallogincallback` requests.

Based on the `Availability and performance` section in the Azure portal, I see slow requests to `/identity/externallogincallback` gone after a few days (approx 7 days):
[image]

Also, I see 3 5xx errors during this period, most likely these errors are related to `/identity/externallogincallback` request timeout:
[image]

After that verified the Master DB DTU and it was returning 100% spikes all time so I have increased it to 50 DTU.
[image]

Hope it helps to analyze the issue if someone faced the same.